# Custom Post Types and independent Categories - complex Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

Input data:

1. There is a Custom Post Type, with `Companies` posts that relates
       to `Company` category;
2. There is a Custom Post Type, with
       `Products` posts that tied to `Items -> Item-type` category;
3. There is a Custom Post Type, with `Articles` posts that tied to
       `Articles` category;

Summarizing, structure looks like this:

```
+ Companies (cat)
   |- Company-1 (post)
   `- Company-2
+ Items (cat)
   `- Item-type-1 (cat)
   |   |- Product-1-1 (post)
   |   `- Product-1-2
   `- Item-type-2 (cat)
       |- Product-2-1 (post)
       `- Product-2-2
+ Articles (cat)
   |- Article-1 (post)
   `- Article-2
```

The Problem:

I'll be appreciate for a way to implement the structure that can be accessed like this:

```
http://example.com/company-1/items/item-type-1/product-1 
http://examplecom/company-2/items/item-type-1/product-1 //(note that both company 1 and 2 can produce a similar product)
http://example.com/company-1/articles/article-1-1
http://example.com/company-2/articles/article-2-1
```

Both Products and Articles posts have got a custom fields that stores post-IDs of companies they're tied to.

UPDATE:

I was thinking about developing it with custom taxonomies:

```
http://example.com/post-type-company/taxonomy-item/term-item-type/product
```

Can you advice more suitable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress, the slug (post name) is unique per post type.

So, an url like `/company-1/items/item-type-1/product-1` and one like `/company-2/items/item-type-1/product-1` where `product-1` is the post name, *cannot* address to 2 different products.

If you create 2 products with same *title* Wordpress on saving will set an **unique** slug.

Same thing is for articles.

For this reason in a url like:

```
http://example.com/company-1/items/item-type-1/product-1
```

can simply be rewritten in

```
http://example.com/index.php?post_type=products&name=product-1
```

and a url like:

```
http://example.com/company-1/articles/article-1-1
```

can simply be rewritten in

```
http://example.com/index.php?post_type=articles&name=article-1-1
```

So, as you can see, no matter for category.

You need only 2 rewrite rules:

```
add_action('init','my_rewrite_rules');

function my_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '[^/]+/items/[^/]+/(.+)/?$' , 'index.php?post_type=products&name=$matches[1]' , 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '[^/]+/articles/(.+)/?$' , 'index.php?post_type=articles&name=$matches[1]' , 'top' );
}
```

After that you have to flushing rewrite rules going *Settings->Permalink* section in your backend and saving changes.

Now the urls work as you expect, if you manually write them on browser, but the *problem* is generate the right url using `the_permalink` function. You have to use the 'post_link' filter and generate the right url:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'my_custom_permalink', 99, 3);

function my_custom_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if ( $post->post_type == 'products' )
     return products_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename);
  if ( $post->post_type == 'articles' )
     return articles_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename);
  return $permalink;
}

function products_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if ( $post->post_type != 'products' ) return $permalink;
  $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  $companies = get_term_by('slug', 'companies', 'category');
  $items= get_term_by('slug', 'items', 'category');
  if ( empty($cats) || empty($companies) || empty($items) ) return $permalink;
  $item = '';
  $company = '';
  while ( ! empty($cats) ) {
    if ( $item && $company )
      return home_url() . '/' . $company . '/items/' . $item . '/' . $post->name;
    $cat = array_pop($cats);
    if ( $cat->parent == $companies->term_id ) $company = $cat->slug;
    if ( $cat->parent == $items->term_id ) $item = $cat->slug;
  }
  return $permalink;
}

function articles_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if ( $post->post_type != 'articles' ) return $permalink;
  $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  $companies = get_term_by('slug', 'companies', 'category');
  if ( empty($cats) || empty($companies) ) return $permalink;
  $company = '';
  while ( ! empty($cats) ) {
    if ( $company )
      return home_url() . '/' . $company . '/articles/' . $post->name;
    $cat = array_pop($cats);
    if ( $cat->parent == $companies->term_id ) $company = $cat->slug;
  }
  return $permalink;
}
```

Here I assume you are using only standard categories, where the category 'Companies' is the parent category for companies and 'Items' is the parent category for items.

Also assumed cpt are named 'products' and 'articles' (note the plural).

Ajust the functions if something is different in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but I have 2 points that still not clear:
1) When I'm talking about product-1 under /company-1/ and /company-2/ URLs I mean that a single(unique) Product can be found under both Companies, so `company-1/../product-1` and `company-2/../product-1` url technically should direct us to the same page, but..
2) To avoid search-engine side inconveniences (2 links can't point at the same data), i need that /company-X/ part in url to build a custom layout for a page (example: including company name as header, etc.) 
Can you please advice me, how can i deal with it

Comment: This is problematic. The url, if manually inserted, works for both companies. (for a non-limited number of companies). But the function that create the url, will always create one url. For this reason and to avoid SEO inconvenience if the product is unique, the url should be unique. However you you absolutely need have 2 url for same product, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` var to recognize the `company-*` part and manipulate the content according to it. But I can't find a way to create 2 different url when you call `the_permalink` @IgnatB.